# Managing player specific variable

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to give player a powerup, but only after touching a brick. The powerup should be permanent from that point on. I don't need to store it for later play sessions. How do i store player-specific information for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a "PowerUp" variable (BoolValue) for every player that joins the game:

```
-- Add a "PowerUp" variable to every player that joins the game
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local powerUp = Instance.new("BoolValue", player)
    powerUp.Name = "PowerUp"    
end)


-- Set "PowerUp" to true, when player touches part
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(touchedPart)

    local char = touchedPart.Parent
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(char)
    if (player == nil) then return end

    player.PowerUp.Value = true     
end)
```

Comment: Where would I place this script? I added it to local script under StarterPlayerScripts but its not invoked so obviously not the right place for it. Also, assuming the answer is that this belongs in a server script, will I be able to access it from a local script (to check if the player has the powerup). BTW, any references to relevant articles will be very welcome :)

Comment: I would put it into ServerScriptService. That's a place for scripts that are executed on the server only (ie. they don't get replicated to the clients). The instance of "BoolValue" however that is created on the server, will be replicated to the client, so yes, you can see it from client scripts and you can also have it fire events to your client script if the value changes.